# How to output results of multiple queries together?

Tags: sql, union

I want to display result of 3 selects together in one window, in the same time.

First:

```
SELECT sum(r.punkty)
    ,r.id_kierowcy
FROM wyniki AS r
INNER JOIN wyscigi AS w ON r.id_wyscigu = w.id_wyscigu
WHERE w.rok = 2006
GROUP BY r.id_kierowcy
ORDER BY sum(r.punkty) DESC limit 1
```

Second:

```
  SELECT sum(r.punkty)
    ,r.id_kierowcy
FROM wyniki AS r
INNER JOIN wyscigi AS w ON r.id_wyscigu = w.id_wyscigu
WHERE w.rok = 2000
GROUP BY r.id_kierowcy
ORDER BY sum(r.punkty) DESC limit 1
```

Third:

```
SELECT sum(r.punkty)
    ,r.id_kierowcy
FROM wyniki AS r
INNER JOIN wyscigi AS w ON r.id_wyscigu = w.id_wyscigu
WHERE w.rok = 2012
GROUP BY r.id_kierowcy
ORDER BY sum(r.punkty) DESC limit 1
```

In brief there is one difference in the selects, that is `WHERE [2000, 2006, 2012]`
Is the way to connect these selects? I must display them as one result set

**EDIT**: I will try to explain my exercise.
I have 2 tables:
Results and races.

Results contains 3 columns:
id_driver
/points
/id_race

Races contains 3 columns:
id_race
/year
/place

Races are between 2000 and 2012 years
I need to do classification of races in the 2000, 2006, 2012 and establish which one driver(id_driver) won each year. So I'm trying to do like that

```
SELECT sum(r.points)
    ,r.id_driver
FROM results AS r
INNER JOIN races AS x ON r.id_race = x.id_race
WHERE x.year = 2012
GROUP BY r.id_driver
ORDER BY sum(r.points) DESC limit 1
```

and the same for 2006 and 2000, but i need to display that as one result set, that is my problem I dont know how to connect it.

Comment: At a first glance, this is pretty easy with `WHERE w.rock IN (2000, 2006, 2012)`. But... there is a contradictory requirement: `LIMIT 1`. So where is the logic here?

Comment: `UNION ALL` seems to be what you need. 3 independent queries whose results are put together in a single result-set.

Comment: Looks like `WHERE w.rock IN (2000, 2006, 2012)` would solve this, but since you are using the `limit 1`, maybe you should `GROUP BY year` (so it will aggregate by year, and this is the result you want), and `ORDER BY sum(points)` and use your `limit`. This way you will get the higher pontuation of the groups 2000, 2006, 2012.

Comment: Please check my post one more time, I edited it. When I use `WHERE w.rok IN (2000, 2006, 2012)` I get wrong results. When I try to use UNION ALL I get error `#1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY`

Comment: @Stwosch Which database are your use? MSSQL has a `rank()` function.

Comment: I use MySQL, this exercise is designed for Access on my test but I prefer to use SQL. Do you think that can be reason of  difficulty writing it in SQL?

Comment: Both Access and MySQL are less SQL standard compliant. They are both a bit different, in different ways.